# Comparing a list of values

Tags: sql

For example, I have a head-table with one column id and a position-table with id, head-id (reference to head-table => 1 to N), and a value. Now I select one row in the head-table, say id 1. I look into the position-table and find 2 rows which referencing to the head-table and have the values 1337 and 1338. Now I wanna select all heads which have also 2 positions with these values 1337 and 1338. The position-ids are not the same, only the values, because it is not a M to N relation. Can anyone tell me a SQL-Statement? I have no idea to get it done :/

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your post and showed just the columns from each table in question with a couple of values each.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value is not repeated for a given headid in the position table, and that it is never NULL, then you can do this using the following logic.  Do a full outer join on the position table to the specific head positions you care about.  Then check whether there is a full match.

The following query does this:

```
select *
from (select p.headid,
             sum(case when p.value is not null then 1 else 0 end) as pmatches,
             sum(case when ref.value is not null then 1 else 0 end) as refmatches
      from (select p.value
            from position p
            where p.headid = <whatever>
           ) ref full outer join
           position p
           on p.value = ref.value and
              p.headid <> ref.headid
      ) t
where t.pmatches = t.refmatches
```

If you do have NULLs in the values, you can accommodate these using coalesce.  If you have duplicates, you need to specify more clearly what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

```
Create table head
(
    id int
)

Create table pos
(
    id int,
    head_id int,
    value int
)
```

and you need to find duplicates by value, then I'd use:

```
  Select distinct p.head_id, p1.head_id
from pos p
join pos p1 on p.value = p1.value and p.head_id<>p1.head_id
where p.head_id = 1
```

for specific head_id, or without last where for every head_id

Comment: **head**
id
1
2
3

**positions**
id, head_id, value
1, 1, 1337
2, 1, 1338
3, 2, 1330
4, 3, 1337
4, 3, 1338

I select the first row of heads ... so i get position with id 1 and 2. Now I want all heads which have the same values (positions). So I want as result the head-id 1 and 3, because the head with id 3 has also 2 positions with value 1337 and 1338. The values-column is a character field, no integer.

Comment: then `Select distinct p.head_id from ...` should give you what you want. Value type does not matter, it is just to illustrate an example.